# How to write JUnit test case for finding first non-repeating character in stream?

Tags: java, junit

Since users are focused more on minor loop holes than requirement, I am giving actual working code (replacing) for which I need junit test case.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FirstNonRepeatingCharacterStream {

    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean[] repeated = new boolean[256];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FirstNonRepeatingCharacterStream tester = 
                new FirstNonRepeatingCharacterStream();
        while (true) {
            Character ch = new Character(sc.next().charAt(0));
            Character output = tester.firstNonRepeatingCharStream1(ch);
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

    public Character firstNonRepeatingCharStream1(Character x) {

        if (x == null) {
            return x;
        }

        Character output = null;

        if (!repeated[x]) {
            if (!chars.contains(x)) {
                chars.add(x);
            } else {
                chars.remove(new Character(x));
                repeated[x] = true;
            }
        }
        if (chars.size() != 0) {
            output = new Character(chars.get(0));
        }
        return output;

    }

}
```

```
User enters one character at a time.
input a -> output a
input b -> that means input ab as it's stream -> output a
input a -> that means input aba as it's stream -> output b
input c -> that means input abac as it's stream -> output b
input b -> that means input abacb as it's stream -> output c
input a -> that means input abacba as it's stream -> output c
input d -> that means input abacbad as it's stream -> output c
```

Please let me know how to write unit test which should comply with main method. Not necessary to have while loop in junit test case.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output that is expected as a result?

Comment: @BlindKai - I have updated above.

Comment: But why you're trying to avoid for/foreach if it's a good way to iterate thro?

Comment: @BlindKai - I have simulated using for loop. That's not ideal. Input is provided at runtime one character at a time.

Comment: Could you add a code that shows the input process?

Comment: @BlindKai - Hope that logic confuses other users here. In Java, we can use Scanner or InputStreamReader to input data at runtime. Please read my other comments below.

Comment: You're not really able to use `Scanner` in unit tests if I'm not wrong. So probably I would recommend you to create static inputs of different variations and test them via parametrized tests.

Comment: @BlindKai - I don't know how to write junit test here. Hence posted it. We don't use Scanner for Junit test which I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

```
class FirstNonRepeatingCharacterStreamTest3 {

    private static FirstNonRepeatingCharacterStream tester;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        tester = new FirstNonRepeatingCharacterStream();
    }

    @DisplayName("MyTest")
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} => input={0}, output= {1}")
    @CsvSource({
        "'a', 'a'",
        "'b', 'a'",
        "'a', 'b'",
        "'c', 'b'",
        "'b', 'c'",
        "'a', 'c'",
        "'d', 'c'"
    })
    public void testFirstNonRepeatingCharStream101(Character input, Character output) {
        Character actual = tester.firstNonRepeatingCharStream1(input);
        assertEquals(output, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would mostly boil down to coming up with "mean" test strings to try and hit various edge cases in your code:

```
String testStrings[] {
    null,
    "", // empty string
    "a", // easiest possible string with a match
    "aa", // easiest possible string with no match
    "aba", // slightly less easy string with a match
    "aaaaa", // no match on N instances of a character
    "aaaaab", // match on end of N instances of a character
    "baaaaa", // match at beginning of N instances of a character
    "aabaaa", // match in the middle of N instances of a character
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", // harder string where the unique letter is in the middle (z)
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb", // harder string where the unique character is at the front (a)
    "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", // harder string where the unique character is at the back
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy" // other harder string... etc.
};
```

You then develop a similar array of expected output, and then you blaze through all of your cases in a single `for(int i = 0;...)` loop.

Another way of developing test input would be to generate test strings algorithmically, such that all the characters occur in pairs in one of three strategies (aabbcc, abccba, abcabc), then poke out the first character, then the last character, then one in the middle (you check which character you're removing first and that becomes your test value).

Lots of different ways to skin this cat.

PS: Your current code will break with `null` or any character whose "integer" value is greater than 255.  Lots of kooky Unicode characters out there... I seem to recall hearing that several dead and fictional languages are now in Unicode (Ancient Egyptian, JJR Tolkien's Elvish, Klingon, etc), to say nothing of the CJKV range (Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Vietnamese).  Lots of "code points" out there beyond 256.

Comment: Please forget boundary conditions for now. I assume unit test should be developed usining ```@Repeat``` or ```@RepeatTest``` annotations. But I have no clue how to write working example.

Comment: Forget boundary conditions?  I think you're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: Please help me to solve my requirement which I mentioned in my original post if you know. I think we can avoid irrelevant discussion. My code is working if input is given. Edge cases I can take care later.